I can't install packages directly from Github
I need face_recognition library (python) for my project but i can't install it without Visual Studio. I want to install the package from Github directly. I tried pip install https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git and pip install https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git#egg=face_recognition
`
What should I do?
I want a code without pip install https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git or pip install https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git#egg?face_recognition
Thank you very much! :)

When you tried those things, what happened?  Were there errors?  What were the error messages?  What have do done to address them?  Did you follow the installation instructions?

That's the error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iL9C7094vO31RBDINde5iNGGaOsCM7vjX0C9Qeenz3g/edit?usp=sharing

What OS are you using? According to the face recognition git repository, you can install it by running pip3 install face_recognition, given that you have cmake installed.

I know and I tried but when it write  "Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ..." it gave me this message:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iL9C7094vO31RBDINde5iNGGaOsCM7vjX0C9Qeenz3g/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using Windows 10
